# Problems loading pygtk on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygtk

I'm trying to use pygtk in Python but when I try running my code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 3, in <module>
    pygtk.require(2.0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygtk.py", line 85, in require
    "required version '%s' not found on system" % version
AssertionError: required version '2.0' not found on system
```

Here is the code I'm trying to run (it's basically the Hello World example from the pygtk website):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pygtk
pygtk.require(2.0)
import gtk

class Application():
  def hello(self, widget, data=None):
    print 'Hello World'

  def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
    print 'delete even occurred'
    return False

  def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()

  def __init__(self):
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.connect('delete_event', self.delete_event)
    self.quitButton = Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
    self.quitButton.grid()
    self.window.set_border_width(10)
    self.button = gtk.Button('Hello World')
    self.button.connect('clicked', self.hello, None)
    self.button.connect_object('clicked', gtk.Widget.destroy, self.window)
    self.window.add(self.button)
    self.button.show()

  def main(self):
    gtk.main()

def main():
  app = Application()
  app.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Also, when I try running `pygtk-demo` everything works ok, even though it is importing the library the same way that I am. Also it outputs `PyGTK Demo (gtk: v2.24.4,  pygtk: v2.22.0)` so you can see that I have a version that is >2.0.

Comment: Does `dir(pygtk)` give you a version number or a function/attribute to call/read to find out? You may have two version installed.

Comment: Ok, so using that I found `pygtk._get_available_versions()` which returns `{'2.0': '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0'}`.

Comment: Change to `pygtk.require('2.0')`; because `2.0` should be string, not float.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm stupid, that was it! You should repost this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks, @erisco, for prompting for more information; which allowed the error to be more-easily identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd line in your file should read:

```
pygtk.require('2.0')
```

Because `2.0` is a string in this case, not a float.